# Spring Boot JNDI CommonJ resource

Tags: java, spring, jndi, apache-tomee

Trying to get WorkManagers working with CommonJ in a Spring Boot app, hosted in TomEE.

Currently have the following configuration:

Tomcat context.xml

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="myWorkManager"
    auth="Container"
    type="commonj.work.WorkManager"
    factory="de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory"
    maxThreads="5" />
  <ResourceLink
    name="myWorkManager"
    global="myWorkManager"
    type="commonj.work.WorkManager" />
</Context>
```

Spring app web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>myWorkManager</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

This is currently throwing the following exception when the app loads:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManager] available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/myWorkManager] is not assignable to [commonj.work.WorkManager]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:182)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 53 more
```

I have the CommonJ jars downloaded from http://commonj.myfoo.de/install.shtml in my Tomcat lib directory.

I feel like I'm getting pretty close but slightly puzzled by this exception.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

If I remove the two CommonJ jars from TomEE lib folder, I get this exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commonj.work.WorkManager

Which is what I would expect.

If I remove the factory property from the resource element I get:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException:
>   Object of type [class org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext]
>   available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/wm/default] is not
>   assignable to [commonj.work.WorkManager]

Comment: Make sure you don't have the jars in your web application.

Comment: Have updated based on your suggestion

Comment: No you haven't... You shouldn't remove them from the tomcat lib but you should remove them from your applications lib directory i.e WEB-INF/lib. You also appear NOT to be using Tomcat but TomEE which is a bit of a different beast.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am using TomEE, will update question

Comment: I've also confirmed these jars are not in my application either

Answer (score 1):

Im encounter with same issue, when try to start my app locally in maven-jetty-plugin. [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) comment was very helpful. This error happens if you have lib jar in shared lib of your Application Server and in your WEB-INF/lib folder of web application, because server use one jar to create resource (parent classloader), but application use self jar(child classloader) and it two different classes hierarchy, so FooWorkManager cant be cast to WorkManager.